# Set a prefix path for I18n keys within non-standard Rails classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

A Rails project of mine uses `rails-i18n` for localization purposes. From within views (ActionView) and controllers (ActionController) one can call the (`I18n.`)`t` method to get values from the appropriate locale YAML.

If you start the localization-key with a period, like `t(".title")`, Rails will add a prefix path for the file you're currently in, using a feature called [lazy lookup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup). So the `".title"`-key get's a prefix from within your `users/show.html.erb` file to become `"users.show.title"`.

Works like a charm, but now I have a couple of classes that are neither views, nor controllers, and I want to use the `t`-method from there as well. Calling `I18n.t` works fine, but because my custom class doesn't inherit from any Rails classes, it doesn't get a prefix. I can work around this quite easily, but all my workarounds look ugly, and I have the feeling there's a method in one of the super classes that's used to determine the prefix — but I can't find it in the documentation.

Is there a (class-)method one can override, that `I18n.t` uses for the lazy lookup?

Answer (score 2):

I guess if it's good enough for [ActionPack's `AbstractController::Translation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3bf961d7fd01c79cd6748e7f6531e341e47a6ef1/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/translation.rb#L11), it's good enough for me to copy in my custom class scenario:

```
def translate(*args)
  key = args.first
  if key.is_a?(String) && (key[0] == '.')
    key = "#{ controller_path.tr('/', '.') }.#{ action_name }#{ key }"
    args[0] = key
  end

  I18n.translate(*args)
end
alias :t :translate
```

(wherein I'll replace the `controller_path` part)